# Find the year which has highest number of active bonds

Tags: python

Given two lists:

1. Issue year of bonds
2. Maturity year of bond

Something like:

```
issue_year = [1934, 1932, 1945, 1946, ...]
mature_years = [1967, 1937, 1957, 1998, ...]
```

With this example, the first bond has issue-year of 1934, and maturity year of 1967, while the second bond has issue-year of 1932 and maturity year of 1937, and so on.

The problem I am trying to solve is to find the year which has the highest number of active bonds.

Here is what I have so far. This finds the year in which all bonds are active.

```
L1=[1936,1934,1937]
L2=[1940,1938,1940]

ctr=0
for i in range(len(L1)):
    j=i
    L3=list(range(L1[i],L2[j]))
    if ctr==0:
       tempnew=L3
    else:
       tempnew=list(set(L3) & set(tempnew))

    ctr = ctr+1
```

Here `tempnew` is the intersection of all the active years for all the bonds. But, it might happen that the intersection of all the active years might be empty. For example, if bond 1 were active from 1932 through 1945, and bond 2 is active from 1947 thru 1960.

Can someone help ?

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: @Kahirul Thanx for reply. here is my code, which will take the intersection of all the active years for all bonds.                                                            `L1=[1936,1934,1937]
L2=[1940,1938,1940]
ctr=0
for i in range(len(L1)):
    j=i
    L3=list(range(L1[i],L2[j]))
    #print L3
    
    if ctr==0:
        tempnew=L3
    else:
        tempnew=list(set (L3) & set (tempnew))
    #temp=tempnew
    ctr=ctr+1 `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code which I believe meets your requirements.  It works by scanning through `issue` and `mature` years list using `zip`.  It then fills out a dict whose keys are all of the active years, and whose value are the number of bonds active that year.  Finally it dumps all of the years which have the max number of active bonds:

**Code:**

```
def add_active_years(years, issue, mature):
    for year in range(issue, mature+1):
        years[year] = years.get(year, 0) + 1

# go through the lists and calculate the active years
years = {}
for issue, mature in zip(L1, L2):
    add_active_years(years, issue, mature)

# now reverse the years dict into a count dict of lists of years
counts = {}
for year, count in years.items():
    counts[count] = counts.get(count, []) + [year]

# show the result
print(counts[max(counts.keys())])
```

**Sample Data:**

```
L1 = [1936,1934,1937]
L2 = [1940,1938,1940]
```

**Results:**

```
[1937, 1938]
```

Comment: You are very Welcome.  However on SO, the very best way to say thanks is to upvote *any* answer (or question) you find useful.  This is true even on questions you didn't ask.  Cheers.